# Group cohomology of infinite cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am trying to compute the group homologies $H^n(G,M)$ on a $G$-module $M$ where $G$ is the infinite cyclic group. I think I managed to get the case $n = 0$ and $n > 1$, but I'm unsure about the remaining case. My work is as follows.

Let $x$ be a generator of $G$, then the augmentation ideal is given by $IG = \langle x-1 \rangle$. This creates a short exact sequence $0 \to IG \xrightarrow{\iota} \mathbb{Z}[G] \xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$ where $\iota$ is the inclusion, and $\epsilon$ the augmentation map. Since $IG$ is infinitely cyclic, it is a free group, therefore this sequence can be considered a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$. The Hom functor induces the following sequence on the respective deleted resolution.

\begin{equation}
 0 \to \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[G],M) \xrightarrow{\iota^\ast} \text{Hom}(IG,M) \to 0 \to 0 \to \cdots
\end{equation}

Consider an arbitrary $f \in \text{Ker}(\iota^\ast)$, which means $f \circ \iota = 0$ per definition of the induced map. Since these maps are defined over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, it follows that $f(x - 1) = (x - 1) \cdot f(1) = 0$. This defines a unique map for every choice of $f(1) \in M[x - 1]$. If there are two maps $f, g \in \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[G],M)$ such that $f(1) = g(1)$ then for arbitrary $z \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$ follows that $f(z) = z \cdot f(1) = z \cdot g(1) = g(z)$. Therefore a map is uniquely defined by its image $f(1)$. This concludes $H^0(G,M) = \text{Ker}(\iota^\ast) \cong M[x-1]$.

I'm a bit lost on what to do next. Clearly the only other (potentially) non-trivial homology is $H^1(G,M)$. I'm not mistaken this homology is equal to $\text{Hom}(IG,M)/\text{Img}(\iota^\ast)$ right? I would think any $f \in \text{Hom}(IG,M)$ can be written as $f = g \circ \iota$ for some $g \in \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[G],M)$. Is that enough to conclude $H^1(G,M) = 0$ as well?

Edit: The thing that sort of makes me hesitant about my results is, if this is true, then I should be able to show any group extension $0 \to M \to E \to G \to 1$ is equivalent to the trivial one. But I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: "Since IG is infinitely cyclic, it is a free group" - this is not true, *and* if it were it would not imply what you said. $\mathbb Z[G]$ is not finitely generated as an abelian group, so $IG$ can't be either. But that's beside the point, because you don't want it to be free *as an abelian group*, you want it to be free or projective as a $\mathbb Z[G]$-module, which is a completely different question. Now, as a $\mathbb Z[G]$-module, it is indeed generated by $x-1$, and so being free is equivalent to $x-1$ not being a zero-divisor in $\mathbb Z[G]$

Comment: Right, thank you, I suppose I got the two definitions mixed up. But if I follow you correctly that means everything else still holds i.e. that is still a free resolution I put together there?

Comment: It is a free resolution, but your computation of $H^1$ is wrong in general : not every $f$ can be written that way. In fact what you can prove is that your complex is isomorphic to $(x-1) : M\to M$. So its kernel is $M[x-1] = M^G$, and the cokernel is $M/(x-1)M$ which is far from $0$ in general (for instance, if $M$ is a trivial $G$-module !)

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thank you. I suppose being able to extend a module map from a submodule to the entire thing is not as straightforward as extending an actual linear map. Now that I think about it I imagine it's not straightforward for infinite-dimensional vector spaces either